# Google App Engine Python, stylesheet doesn't load

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, app.yaml

I have an HTML page that gets written by Python onto my appspot domain. However, my stylesheet doesn't load! In the dev console, there are no errors, and when I check the resources tab, the stylesheet is not there.

HTML Link:

```
    <link rel= type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/style_home.css"/>
```

File hierarchy:

```
-/

 -stylesheets

     -style_home.css
```

app.yaml:

```
- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Also, for the html link, I tried the `href` with and without the preceding `/`, but it still didn't work. Thanks!

~Carpetfizz

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing the secure: always

app.yaml:

```
handlers:
    - url: /stylesheets
      static_dir: stylesheets
      secure: always
```